# Get a list of functions, classes and variables in a Java Source code using Antlr

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I am using ANTLR for parsing Java source code. This is the current code which prints (outputs to a file) all the variable/function/class declarations with their line and column numbers in a file using `ParseTreeWalker`.

```
Java8Lexer lex = new Java8Lexer(input);
lex.setTokenFactory(new CommonTokenFactory(true));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);
ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new Java8DeclarationListener(), parser.compilationUnit());
```

But I want to store all the names and the corresponding information in a data structure like an `ArrayList` instead of writing them to a file. How can I do this ?

Comment: The code you have here doesn't actually output anything.  I expect the output is in `Java8DeclarationListener` which you omitted.

Comment: `Java8DeclarationListener` just implements the methods defined in the `Java8BaseListener` interface class (this class file has no definition for any of it's methods, thus an interface class). It's for printing the variable and function declaration names. I don't want to use the `Java8BaseListener` class generated by ANTLR. I want to just go through the AST and identify a node through it's type and print what it is. Also, I need to explore the relationship between a parent and child node, like the between a class and it's method, and print this relationship as well. @mrjink

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. I copied your code to a project, and nothing was output. I had to implement the ParseTreeListener to have it output anything. That's why I said that. Search your project for access to the file you're writing and reverse engineer it?

Comment: I figured it out, but now I am having issues with choosing a design pattern for this project. I need to have extensiblity for parsing other source codes in other languages as well. Which design pattern should I follow ? @mrjink

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  This is a different question entirely and largely depends on the rest of your project.  You should probably ask a new question.